# How to add loader when data is fetched from api in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuex

I create an VueJS/Vuex app to get data from API and display this data on another page,
logic of this site is that the user click on button to get data on `first` page but this data must be displayed on another page,

here is my code:

```
data.js

import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
    data: ''
};

const getters = {
    getData: (state) => {
        return state.data;
    }
};

const actions = {
    async fetchData({ commit }, { id }) {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://someUrl?id=${id}`);
        console.log(response.data);
        commit('setData', response.data);
    }
}

const mutations = {
    setData: (state, data) => (state.data = data)
}

export default {
    state, getters, actions, mutations
}
```

Vue file where i want to fetch this data:

```
<script>
  import FooterComponent from "@/components/Footers/Footer.vue";

  import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        id: ""
      }
    },
    name: "Index",
    methods: {
      ...mapActions(["fetchData"]),
      launchFetchData() {
        this.fetchData({ id: this.id})
        this.$router.push("login");
      }
    },
    computed: mapGetters(["getData"])
  }
</script>
```

so, How to check by status whether the data has been correctly downloaded and how to redirect to the appropriate page when the data has been correctly downloaded? And how to add simply loader when the data is downloaded?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but could you please try this ?

```
<script>
  import FooterComponent from "@/components/Footers/Footer.vue";

  import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        id: "",
        data: null
      }
    },
    name: "Index",
    methods: {
      launchFetchData() {
        try {
         ...mapActions(["fetchData"]),
        this.fetchData({ id: this.id})
        this.data = mapGetters(["getData"])
        this.$router.push("login");
        } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        }
      }
    },
   mounted() 
      this.launchFetchData()
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I also added the try{}catch{} syntax to make sure you wont be redirect if there's an error. So the error will be displayed in the console.